# Moved hosts, how do I view the site?

Tags: hosting, dns, windows-xp

I recently moved hosts with my blog and I have waited 72 hours for it t propergate properly. I just checked the site there and it's showing it on the old host. When i use a proxy, I can see the site perfectly on the new host. The problem seems to becoming from my PC.

**EDIT: Tried to flush the dns and it's the same story, it's quite weird.**

Any idea?

Comment: You should indicate the domain names otherwise we cannot test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your old DNS records will live in various DNS caches until their TTL (time-to-live) timers expire.
Best practice is to revise your DNS records well before the move, and pull the TTL (time-to-live) timeout values low, leaving enough time for the old records to timeout and get refreshed with the short-TTL records.  Then after the move you put the TTL values up on the new records (for efficiency).

Now that you're in this situation, you'll have to put up with the inconsistency until all the cached records expire.  If you have a way to put an HTTP redirect on the old web server, pointing to an IP URL, that could tide you over in the short run.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would I go about setting the Time to Live value?

Comment: Whoever runs the DNS servers for your domain has to do it.  Hopefully they offer that option.

Meanwhile, perhaps the reason you're getting the old record is because that's what's in your ISP's cache.

Comment: Daniel Von Fange's suggestion to use the "hosts" file to work around the problem on your host is a fine idea.  Just keep in mind that everybody else in the world may have old records too.

Answer (score 3):

Your ISP is the one the one caching the record. Uses a hosts file http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file to temporarily force your computer to use the new ip address.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have the DNS cached on your box.  This could be cached on your PC or at your DNS server.  Short term options; can try to flush your DNS cache, you can edit your hosts file to temporarily point at the right location.

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt and type:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

then try your site again.

Answer (score 0):

I see this:

www.keithdonegan.com [81.17.254.87]

My DNS changes always propagate in minutes, a couple of hours at the most.

Comment: How many comments are here? http://www.keithdonegan.com/irelands-dragons-den/ is it's 4, that's the old host

Comment: I'm using opendns and your site doesn't come up at all for me.

Comment: Not using OpenDNS and site is also down as of this nugget in time

Comment: I just used opendns there and it works perfectly, thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: Site now seen, with 6 comments thus